# How to make a program with 2 windows that open simultaneously upon runtime in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Initially I made it in the main of the window I had made earlier

Comment: From what type is `recieverWindow` derived from? Usually, a widget becomes an independent window if there is no parent widget (set or given initially). So, even a simple `QLabel` or `QPushButton` can become a window as well. The exception is `QDialog` which becomes an independent window in any case. (If the parent is set, it becomes a transient dialog, otherwise not.) You used `new recieverWindow(this)` in your code - hence my question. Btw. I still don't get how this can lead to a crash. There must be something else...

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] to reproduce your issue? (I would appreciate if the [mcve] would setup the widgets "manually" instead of using a UI definition.)

Comment: @Scheff I made some editions I hope they are useful and give you more of an insight into my code

Comment: Sorry, that's still no [mcve]. (A [mcve] makes your issue reproducable for readers - i.e. copy/paste the code and try myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing complicated to open a 2<sup>nd</sup> window (or dialog) with the main window.

To demonstrate this, I made an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

C++ source `testQMainWindowWithQDialog.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

class Dialog: public QDialog {
  private:
    QVBoxLayout _qVBox;
    QLabel _qLbl;

  public:
    Dialog(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QDialog(pQParent),
      _qLbl("the dialog")
    {
      setWindowTitle("the Dialog Window");
      _qVBox.addWidget(&_qLbl, 1, Qt::AlignCenter);
      setLayout(&_qVBox);
    }

    virtual ~Dialog() = default;

    Dialog(const Dialog&) = delete;
    Dialog& operator=(const Dialog&) = delete;
};

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
  private:
    Dialog _qDlg;
    QWidget _qWidgetCentral;
    QVBoxLayout _qVBox;
    QLabel _qLbl;

  public:
    MainWindow():
      QMainWindow(),
      _qDlg(this),
      _qLbl("the main window")
    {
      setWindowTitle("Test QMainWindow with QDialog");
      _qVBox.addWidget(&_qLbl, 1, Qt::AlignCenter);
      _qWidgetCentral.setLayout(&_qVBox);
      setCentralWidget(&_qWidgetCentral);
      _qDlg.show();
    }
};

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  MainWindow qWinMain;
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Build script `CMakeLists.txt` (to prepare a VS solution for VS2017):

```
project(QMainWindowWithQDialog)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQMainWindowWithQDialog testQMainWindowWithQDialog.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQMainWindowWithQDialog Qt5::Widgets)
```

Built and run on Windows 10, VS2017, Qt 5.13:

[image: snapshot of testQMainWindowWithQDialog.exe (main window)] [image: snapshot of testQMainWindowWithQDialog.exe (dialog)]

a Qt project file `testQMainWindowWithQDialog.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQMainWindowWithQDialog.cc

QT += widgets
```

Built and tested on [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) (with X11 server):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQMainWindowWithQDialog.pro 

$ make && ./testQMainWindowWithQDialog 
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQMainWindowWithQDialog.o testQMainWindowWithQDialog.cc
g++  -o testQMainWindowWithQDialog.exe testQMainWindowWithQDialog.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: snapshot of ./testQMainWindowWithQDialog (main window)] [image: snapshot of ./testQMainWindowWithQDialog (dialog)]

I still believe that there must be something else wrong in OP's code.

Comment: Turns out the error occurred due to the fact that I had accidentally deleted the instantiation of QPushButton pointer in the main function. This probably made the connect function make very little sense to the compiler and so it made the program crash.